# Error in using QueryDef to define parameters in a query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm working in Access and trying to use a query with parameters in VBA.  I have several queries that I need to use, so I added a routine to generalize the process:

```
Public Function Execute_query(query) As Recordset

Dim qdf As QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(query)
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
    Next prm

If (qdf.Type = 80) Then
    qdf.Execute
    Else: Set Execute_query = qdf.OpenRecordset
    End If
End Function
```

I'm still testing this so there may be other issues, but my immediate question is why the `Eval(prm.name)` line isn't working.  The paramater is [R_Yr] which I've declared as a public variable and have assigned a value - which I can verify in the watch window.  But I get an error code 2482 - Access cannot find the name 'R_yr"

This same code seems to work when the parameter value is coming from a form instead of a variable - which is why I had to set it up in the first place - I couldn't access a form control in a query run from VBA.

Comment: I've tried a few more things in the watch window: with x="[R_yr]" Eval(x) doesn't work with x="R_yr", it doesn't work but Eval(R_yr) works just fine so how do I get rid of the quotes in this case?

Comment: and how do I get line breaks into a comment?

Comment: RE: "how do I get line breaks into a comment?" - You don't. In many cases (like this one) it is better to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16716537/edit) your question with additional information. It improves the quality of the question, and it saves future readers from having to dredge through all of the comments to get the pertinent details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me, but I'm having a bit of trouble seeing the real benefit from this extra level of indirection. You have to create variables that correspond to the parameters for the particular query you are planning to invoke, and then you call a generic function to invoke it. Why not just create a QueryDef, pass it the parameters, and invoke it in place? It seems like essentially the same amount of work, and it makes the code easier to follow because "everything is right there".

Comment: Thank you - I guess I was trying too hard.  I had all the parameters defined for other purposes in my calling function and thought I could do a one line function call instead of a querydef - but that worked fine with just a few extra lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

`Eval()` takes the string you give it and uses the *"expression service"* to process it.  The problem you're facing is the expression service doesn't know anything about VBA variables.  If you're really determined, you may be able to figure out a workaround which builds the variable's *value* rather than the variable's *name* into the string you give `Eval()` to ... um ... evaluate.

But for what you're doing, I suggest you ditch `Eval()`.  Instead give the function a data structure such as a `Scripting.Dictionary` or VBA `Collection` which contains the parameter values with your former variable names as keys.

Here is a VBA `Collection` example ...

```vb
Dim MyCol As Collection
Set MyCol = New Collection
MyCol.Add CLng(10), "R_Yr"
MyCol.Add "foo", "MyString"
Debug.Print MyCol("R_Yr"), TypeName(MyCol("R_Yr"))
Debug.Print MyCol("MyString"), TypeName(MyCol("MyString"))
```

That code gives me this output in the Immediate window ...

```vb
 10           Long
foo           String
```

So consider building a similar collection in the calling code and passing that collection to a modified `Execute_query` function.

```vb
Public Function Execute_query(ByVal pQdf As String, _
        ByRef pCol As Collection) As Recordset

    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(pQdf)
    For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
        prm.Value = pCol(prm.Name)
    Next prm

    If (qdf.Type = 80) Then
        qdf.Execute
    Else
        Set Execute_query = qdf.OpenRecordset
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you.  I think this means I need a different collection for each query I use, right?  I was hoping to have a general solution that would be easy to use with any query - something functionally as easy as "set data=currentdb().openrecordset(query)" for a query without parameters.

Comment: Yes.  But the alternative you were persuing is to create a different set of VBA variables corresponding to the parameters for each query.  That does not really seem like *less* work than the approach I suggested.  And the collection avoids the effort you would need to invest to make `Eval()` work ... if you can even do it.

Comment: Except when I am using the same parameters in multiple queries

Comment: Sorry then, I can't offer anything more about `Eval()`.  However, take a closer look at `If (qdf.Type = 80) Then ...`.  Basically you're saying if it's a "make table" query, execute it.  And open a DAO Recordset for any other query type.  However I don't think you really want a recordset from a delete query (type=32), for example.

Comment: +1 for explaining about the "expression service" and that its variable scope is different than the calling procedure.